# Setting NULL to struct pointer, but never NULL when checked

Tags: c, kernel, point

Given, in the function called,

```
void callFunct1 (arg_t *q) {
   q = NULL;
};
EXPORT_SYMBOL(callFunct1);
```

returns a null.

Why is the reason that in another function, q is never NULL? How can I correct it?

```
arg_t qH; 
arg_t* q; 
                                        //
callFunct1 (&qH);
q = &qH;


if (q == NULL) {    
      .....
    }
```

arg_t is just a struct.

Answer (score 3):

Pointers are no different than any other non-array variable in C. When passed as a parameter, if you want to modify something as in/out, you have to pass by address. Declare the parameter to be a formal pointer-to-the-type and pass the address of the entity from the caller, using the dereference operator `*` to access the caller's value.

Just as this:

```
void foo(int *p)
{
    *p = 5;
}
```

is invoked like this:

```
int x;
foo(&x); // x will be 5 on return
```

So it is with pointer-types as well. If you want to modify the pointer by address then the address is precisely what is needed. Declare the parameter as a pointer-to-pointer-to-`arg_t` and dereference it to set the referenced pointer to NULL:

```
void foo(arg_t** pp)
{
    *pp = NULL;
}
```

and

```
arg_t *p;
foo(&p);  // p will be NULL on return
```

Comment: is there another way by not changing the arg, leaving it to (arg_t *q) as some one is using the same interface for something else later?

Comment: @Babbit Nope. If you want to modify *anything* in C as in/out it has to be done by address, passing said-address as a function who's formal parameter is a pointer to the underlying type. Arrays are an exception because their "value" is already an address (of the first element in the array). That the type is already a pointer makes no difference. Now, if `arg_t` is *already* a pointer type, (like a pointer to `char` or some such), then all you need to do in your code is `*p = NULL` and the underlying `arg_t` will be NULL. Without knowing what `arg_t` actually *is* I can't speculate further.

Comment: The reason is because, if I do not set it to NULL, there may be an else statement after that that states:

memcpy(q->items, list, sizeof list); // where list is another struct copied into it.

Comment: which means I have to do:

memcpy(*q->items, list, sizeof list);

after that instead of using (q->items)?

Comment: The code you've posted, `q` will *never* be NULL outside the scope of the function. You're assigning it the address of an `arg_t`. That automatic variable does not (and cannot) have a NULL address. *Again*, without more code of what you're actually *trying* to do and *why*, the best you'll get is wags and sheer speculation. You need to clarify the problem. (and btw, the ideal syntax is `(*q)->items`, not `*q->items`). And you've not clarified wither in comments or in your question whether `arg_t` is in fact a pointer type, not that it will matter without more clarification of the problem.

Comment: after

arg_t *p;
foo(&p);  // p will be NULL on return

assuming that I do not set to null, but give a struct to it.

p->num no longer works. The device crashed. How shall I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
void callFunct1 (arg_t *q)
```

returns nothing as its return type is declared `void`.

Its argument `q` is a **copy** of the value passed as parameter when `callFunc1` is called, and this copy lives on `callFunc1`'s stack for as long as `callFunc1` runs.

So this line

```
q = NULL;
```

assigns `NULL` to the `q` existing only locally to `callFunc1`.

Answer (score 0):

That function returns nothing. You pass a pointer to a struct. That pointer is a *copy* of the passed pointer, it is not the same variable as in main.

This is what goes on between the lines: if we have a caller like the code below

```
int main()
{
  arg_t some_struct;
  arg_t* some_ptr = &some_struct;

  callFunct1 (some_ptr)
}
```

then upon calling callFunct1

- some_ptr points at some_struct.
- The function parameter `arg_t* q` is allocated on the stack.
- The contents of some_ptr is *copied* into q.
- Both some_ptr and q now point at some_struct.
- Then you set q to point to NULL.
- Then the function ends. q ceases to exist.
- As you have not changed some_ptr, it still points at some_struct.

---

Now if you had not set some_ptr to point at anything, it would have contained any garbage value. When making a debug build of your program, variables are likely set to NULL by default, but there are absolutely no guarantees for this!

So if some_ptr was uninitialized and happened to contain the value NULL when you called the function, it might have appeared as if you successfully set it to NULL. But in reality, you were just plain lucky that your uninitialized variable contained that value.

---

To actually set the variable in main to point at NULL, you would have to do

```
arg_t callFunct1 (void) {
  return NULL;
};

arg_t* some_ptr;
some_ptr = callFunct1 ();
```

Comment: How may I solve this? How do I set it to NULL while keeping the arg type unchanged?

Comment: @Babbit You can't. Either return it as I shown, or alternatively do pass the pointer itself by reference: `void callFunct1 (arg_t** q){ *q = NULL; }`. Both forms are equivalent.